# Fps algorithm error with systemtime

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, frame-rate

I'm having some trouble with an FPS algorithm I have tried to implement into my simulator. The general idea is that I want 60 to be the maximum amount of tick-render cycles per second. Here is my code:

```
public void run() {

    x = 0; //tick is set to 0 originally 
    lastT = System.currentTimeMillis(); //system time in milliseconds

    //tick-render cycle
    while(running == true){

        currentT = System.currentTimeMillis();
        deltaT += currentT - lastT;
        lastT = currentT;

        if(deltaT/tPerTick >= 1){
            tick(); 
            render();
            deltaT = 0; 
        }

    }

    stop(); //stops thread when running =! true
}
```

The constant 'tPerTick' is defined as follows

```
double tPerTick = 1000 / 60
```

Throughout my development of this program I thought that this algorithm was working perfectly, it was only when I traced this algorithm to confirm that I found an issue. Every time the loop cycles (iterates? I'm not sure what the correct word is here) the if statement is found to be true and therefore the tick-render cycle is executed. I did some more tracing (to find why this was happening) and found that the values for deltaT are always well over tPerTick, like way way over (in some cases 19 seconds even though this is clearly not the case). Is there an error somewhere in my code? I think that I must be either using System.currentTimeMillis() wrong or am tracing the algorithm incorrectly.

In the actual simulation it seems to be working fine (not sure why). When I draw the graphics I pass 'x' (the tick) in and write the time to the screen as x / 60 seconds.

Comment: `1000/60` will yield 16 instead of 16.66667. Try `1000/60.0` instead. Besides that `System.currentTimeMillis()` has some precision issues, try `System.nanoTime()` instead (ofc you'll get nano seconds then, keep that in mind).

Comment: @Thomas I'm getting values for deltaT in my trace of about 135000 (135 seconds), I think that is the main problem. Thanks for the tip though I will implement that as well. At first I was using System.nanoTime() and had the same issue.

Comment: Hmm, either your `tick()` and `render()` take a very long time or there's something you didn't post. Besides that, since you're resetting deltaT to 0 anyways, why not just check `if( (currentT - lastT) >= tPerTick) { ... lastT = currentT; }` ?

Comment: @Thomas Thats a good idea. I will try commenting those methods out and seeing if it works then. The thing that I am confused about is that when I run my program not in debug mode it runs fine.

Comment: Ah so it happens only in debug mode? That might be the explanation, debug mode sometimes seems to be veeeery slow (don't know why yet).

Comment: @Thomas I think I have got it. I feel so stupid! Since I'm running the program through debug and taking a long time between cycling the loop, delta T will be very large. Since it uses the actual system time and I have to press buttons to go through it line by line the actual system time is going to be different by about 19 seconds or so haha. Do you know of any way that I can export the values of the variables to a trace table automatically while the program runs (I'm using eclipse)? I am required to trace this algorithm unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know of any such way but it should be possible so there probably is a plugin for that. Maybe some sort of profiler has a logging capability and can be used to trace calls _and_ values (if you're only interested in calls then a profiler should help you definitely). Another way to do it might be to simulate `System.currentTimeMillis()`, i.e. get some samples of how long a run takes without debugging and then use a random number generator to generate delta time in a certain range.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Gets the current system time. If you are going through the algorithm manually in debug mode, 'deltaT' is going to be very large since it will be equal to the time that you take to manually trace through the algorithm.

Comment: Yes,stepping through with a debugger has that effect :) - Good to know you found the error, it would have been hard for me since there were at least two things I didn't know: you had the issue only when debugging and you seem to have had a misconception about `System.currentTimeMillis()`.